# is it possible to get sub array from mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that prints record in an array, but I need one more array in the last field e.g

```
[0] = Array
    [id] => 1
    [name]=> test
    [age]=> 25
    [subjects]=> 3
    [order_details] = array(
                [0] => array(
               'id' => 1
               'company_id'=> 8
               'purchase_invoice_id '=> 102
               'model_id' => 1
               'date' => 2015-12-1
               'IMEI'=>7654367876
               'color' => black     
               'purchase_price' => 500
               'is_sold' => 1
               'is_returned'=>1
           )
```

can any one guide me ? I need order_details in sub array, but please make sure it shouldn't be from php I need one mysql query to sort it out.

Thanks

Comment: Mysql does not return nested array like that. Please show some code.

Comment: @dan08 even more **MySQL doesn't return php array at all** :-) ;-)

Comment: SQL is not an object relationship mapping framework. What you need to do is either return one set of code and do a subselect per array (very inefficient!!! - lots of calls to DB), or more efficiently store your subarray in another table and do a join between the parent record and array then traverse the parents. A good ORM framework will use the join and provide individual records. No idea what's available in PHP.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I was just wondering that if it may be any sql query, anyways thank you so much again.